# What is a programming language to connect to MSSQL 2000 onward without installing anything?

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-xp

I am looking for a coding language that will work on Windows XP from a self contained executable that can connect to a MSSQL server.

it needs to be able to work without having to install any drivers or frameworks so all the .net based languages are out and i cannot figure out how to connect to MSSQL from C++ without .NET or installing a driver like ODBC.

any suggestions on what languages or libraries i could use to achieve this oddly specific task?

Comment: No drivers or frameworks? So (assuming you think using the TCP stack is allowed), you're going to start by implementing the whole TDS protocol? Ambitious, but probably overly broad. On the other hand, this does also look like a "Recommend a Tool" request which is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: I also have to ask, why such old technology? Windows XP is completely unsupported (and has been for 4 years) and support for SQL Server 2000 ended over 5 years ago. I hope you're not using an Intel Processor. :)

Comment: The reason for xp and SQL 2000 is because the clients we work with are running windows pos ready 2009 or sometimes just xp and have zero interest in upgrading.

Comment: Windows XP comes preinstalled with (a version of) MDAC, which includes the SQL OLE DB drivers, so you should be able to build an application that uses OLE DB to connect without further libraries. Even getting a build chain that can build applications for Windows XP is not easy, though -- recent versions of Visual Studio won't qualify. VS 2012 was the last version supporting it. There are, of course, free alternatives -- FreeTDS for the connectivity (won't even need MDAC), MinGW for the building.

Comment: If the SQL Server in question is not local, you can also consider turning the problem around: leave the clients alone but set up an API or proxy that can do the querying on SQL Server and has endpoints so simple that any technology can call it (in other words, HTTPS). This code could even run on SQL Server itself (although there's obvious security issues to consider).